# what is causing eslint errors in my git pre-commit hook, despite having those folders in .eslintignore?

Tags: eslint, githooks

I'm trying to make a GIt pre-commit Hook so that ESLint rules are kept.
when running a git commit I get a list of errors. some of the errors are files that are in the .eslintignore file.
the .eslintignore file is located in the root of my project directory:

my .eslintignore file:

```
node_modules/
.vite/
```

these are the errors:

```
[STARTED] Preparing lint-staged...
[SUCCESS] Preparing lint-staged...
[STARTED] Running tasks for staged files...
[STARTED] package.json — 20 files
[STARTED] **/*.{js,jsx,json} — 16 files
[STARTED] eslint . --fix
[FAILED] eslint . --fix [FAILED]
[FAILED] eslint . --fix [FAILED]
[FAILED] eslint . --fix [FAILED]
[STARTED] Applying modifications from tasks...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up temporary files...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up temporary files...

✖ eslint . --fix:

frontend\.eslintrc.json
  2:10  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token :

frontend\.vite\deps\_metadata.json
  0:0  warning  File ignored by default.  Use a negated ignore pattern (like "--ignore-pattern '!<relative/path/to/filename>'") to override

frontend\.vite\deps\chunk-V42YN7MM.js
  0:0  warning  File ignored by default.  Use a negated ignore pattern (like "--ignore-pattern '!<relative/path/to/filename>'") to override

frontend\.vite\deps\react-dom_client.js
  0:0  warning  File ignored by default.  Use a negated ignore pattern (like "--ignore-pattern '!<relative/path/to/filename>'") to override

frontend\.vite\deps\react.js
  0:0  warning  File ignored by default.  Use a negated ignore pattern (like "--ignore-pattern '!<relative/path/to/filename>'") to override

frontend\file.js
  1:7  error  'r' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

frontend\package-lock.json
  2:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token :

frontend\package.json
  2:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token :

frontend\src\API\api.jsx
  6:30  error  'user' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  8:41  error  'process' is not defined          no-undef

frontend\src\Redux\dataAction.jsx
  5:14  warning  Fast refresh only works when a file only export components. Use a new file to share constant or functions between components  react-refresh/only-export-components
  9:14  warning  Fast refresh only works when a file only export components. Use a new file to share constant or functions between components  react-refresh/only-export-components

frontend\src\Redux\dataReducer.jsx
  6:7  warning  Fast refresh only works when a file only export components. Move your component(s) to a separate file  react-refresh/only-export-components

✖ 13 problems (6 errors, 7 warnings)

husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

tried running

```
npx eslint --fix
```

and nothing changed.

any suggestions to how to make .eslintignore file work and a quick way to get rid of the errors (not one at a time)?